# Problems with two way binding in Angular 6

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular6

I have an input element like so:

```
<input type="text" google-place-search id='city' placeholder="Type to search" name='city' [(ngModel)]='user.city'>
```

I wan to programmatically set the value of this element in certain cases. So I use:

```
setAddress(addressObj){
    this.user.city = addressObj;
}
```

But this does not seem to bind the new value. I can see that setAddress is being called with the right argument being passed in but no change happens to the input element. Am I missing something here?

This is Angular 6.

Edit 1:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
   this.aboutYouComp.setAddress(autocomplete.getPlace().name);
});
```

This is what's calling it

Comment: should work fine. sample here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5pgjkj . you can update the stackblitz to show us your issue.

Comment: It seems to work fine there. Could something in my code prevent the binding?

Comment: as you don't see compiler warnings i don't see a issue either. if you have valid reference to `this.aboutYouComp` then change should reflect on view as well .

Answer (score 0):

Being that you are using two way data-binding, you could just declare the user object with it's properties in the component's class and access it in the template using [()].
But, you also say that the setAddress method is being called. Where is that happening in your code. Because it doesn't seem to be called in the input element?